# Assigning & Using unique Wordpress post IDs for a script on the main index page

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am trying to create a show/hide comment functionality to the posts on the main index page in wordpress. I currently have it working, however since each comment div has the same class and the script shows all divs with that class, when you click on any of the show/hide buttons, all of them on the page open. Here's the script I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".slidingDiv").hide();

$(".show_hide").show();


$(".show_hide").click(function(){

$(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();

});

});
```

Is there a way to make it so that when you click on a show/hide link for a specific post's comments, only that post's comments section will open? I imagine it would require something along the lines of creating a variable that pulls the post ID #, and then using that to modify the click(function() and slideToggle() lines.

Comment: Can you provide the relevant html please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `.show_hide` button is a sibling element of the `.slidingDiv` which contains the comments, like this...

```
<div class="post">
    Blah blah blah.
    <button class="show_hide">Show/Hide Comments</button>
    <div class="slidingDiv">
          Comment 1
          Comment 2
    </div>
 </div>
```

then you can do this in jQuery...

```
$(".show_hide").click(function(){
     $(".slidingDiv", $(this).parent()).slideToggle();
 });
```